# mysql query that joins a parent column and has multiple inner joins

Tags: mysql, database, woocommerce, inner-join

I'm using the wordpress / woocommerce database structure and am looking to make a custom query.

Basically I need to grab all products without a certain variation and I'm having trouble joining the IDs.

A product and a product_variation are both **posts** with associated **postmeta**.
An example schema:

```
wp_posts                  wp_postmeta

ID                        post_id
post_parent               meta_key
post_type                 meta_value
post_status
```

An example of the **wp_posts** table would look like this:

```
id    name      post_parent    meta_key         meta_value
2     tshirt    null 
3     pants     null
4               2              variation_type   red
5               2              variation_type   blue
```

Here you can see 4 posts; 2 products and 2 variations.  The variation's **post_parent** point to the product.  So i have a red and blue tshirt

What I need, is to grab all products **with** a blue variation, meaning I need to join post_parent to id.

This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts wp1
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 
    ON (pm1.post_id = wp1.ID)
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 
    ON (pm2.post_id = wp1.ID)
  JOIN wp_posts wp2 
    ON (wp2.post_parent = wp1.ID)
      AND wp1.post_type   = 'product_variation'
      AND wp1.post_status = 'publish'
      AND pm1.meta_key    = 'groups-groups_read_post' 
      AND pm1.meta_value  = 'vet_read'
      AND pm2.meta_key    = 'variation_type' 
      AND pm2.meta_value  = 'blue'
```

I believe I'm doing the joins wrong.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you change your structure?

Answer (score 0):

This process is pretty complicated as there are a lot of things going on under the hood. In a project of mine I have to grab all the post ids (primary product ids) based on a certain attribute.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT p.post_parent FROM `wp_posts` AS p
LEFT JOIN
    `wp_postmeta` AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
LEFT JOIN
    `wp_postmeta` AS pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
WHERE
    p.post_type = 'product_variation' AND
    (
        (pm.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_size' AND pm.meta_value = "XL") OR
        (pm.meta_key = 'attribute_size' AND pm.meta_value = "XL")
    )   AND
    pm2.meta_key = '_stock' AND pm2.meta_value != '0'
```

I had a variation `size` and I wanted to grab the products who have this variation and is of course not out of stock. You will notice I had to check for the `meta_key` twice because when you enter attribute in product editor page then woocommerce will store it as `attribute_{$attribute_name}` and save it in the attributes section. But if you select it from the dropdown of available attributes those are saved previously then you have to look for `attribute_pa_{$attribute_name}`. I am sure you can modify this `SQL` based on your requirement.

**Note:** If you intend to use this custom query alongside with the `pre_get_posts` to set the `post__in` parameter then regrettably it won't work. Woocommerce has a filter `loop_shop_post_in` that overrides this. Just to let you know.

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out and this is what I needed

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
        LEFT JOIN wp_posts p2 ON (wp_posts.ID = p2.post_parent) AND p2.post_type = 'product_variation'
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON (pm2.post_id = p2.ID) AND pm2.meta_key = 'variation_type' and pm2.meta_value = 'blue'
        WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
        AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
        AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'groups-groups_read_post')
        AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'vet_read';
```

Comment: just for curiosity whats is `variation_type` ?

Comment: @maksbd19 just a fake placeholder for the actual variation-type I'm checking for (it is named something different in woocommerce), sorry for the confusion.